# can i call stripe library if i store it as a string in a variable?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i'd like to have a generic function for retrieving objects from stripe (customers, subscriptions, coupons, etc).

i'm maybe not going about it the correct way, but the function was getting quite long while handling errors for each type of retrieval- i was doing the try catch error handling sample provided by the stripe documentation over and over in the switch.  so i'd like to only have one try catch statement, and have the try evaluate dynamically based on the object type i'm retrieving.  is this possible?  otherwise i can just go back to the very long function with all the try catch statements.

```
function stripe_retrieve_object($objectName,$objectId) {
    switch ($objectName) {
        case "coupon":
            $retrieveStripeCode = "\Stripe\Coupon::retrieve(\"$objectId\");";
            break;
        case "customer":
            $retrieveStripeCode = "\Stripe\Customer::retrieve(\"$objectId\");";         
            break;
        case "subscription":
            $retrieveStripeCode = "\Stripe\Subscription::retrieve(\"$objectId\");";
            break;
        default:
            echo "There was a generic error.  We were unable to retrieve payment data, and no updates to payment were made.  Please contact admin@email.com";
    } # switch ($objectName) {
    try {
        $stripeTry = eval($retrieveStripeCode);
        return $stripeTry;
    catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) { ... }
} # function stripe_retrieve_object($objectName,$objectId)
```

i see in the logs at stripe that the call is being made to retrieve the object, but the response body is empty on the stripe dashboard, and nothing returns from the $stripeTry = eval($retrieveStripeCode);  i tried var_dump($stripeTry) and it came back NULL.

Comment: Have you echoed `$retrieveStripeCode` out so you can make sure it's actually what you think it is?

Comment: yes.  for example, when i enter coupon as the $objectName it echos to:  \Stripe\Coupon::retrieve("the_coupon_code");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [variable functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) instead of `eval()`.

Note that PHP 7.x is required to use `'ClassName::methodName'` as variable functions.

```
function stripe_retrieve_object($objectName,$objectId) {
    $
    switch ($objectName) {
        case "coupon":
            $retrieveStripeCode = '\Stripe\Coupon::retrieve';
            break;
        case "customer":
            $retrieveStripeCode = '\Stripe\Customer::retrieve';        
            break;
        case "subscription":
            $retrieveStripeCode = '\Stripe\Subscription::retrieve';
            break;
        default:
            echo "There was a generic error.  We were unable to retrieve payment data, and no updates to payment were made.  Please contact admin@email.com";
    } # switch ($objectName) {
    try {
        $stripeTry = $retrieveStripeCode($objectId);
        return $stripeTry;
    catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) { ... }
}
```

Comment: i'm on a new enough version of php that this worked for me.  thanks php friend!